# Local variable "app" referenced before assignment (production environment)

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm handling different environments with `os.environ.get()` and in my production-like environment
I've got `FLASK_ENV` set to `staging`

```
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app(script_info=None):
    if os.environ.get('FLASK_ENV') == 'staging':
        app = Flask(__name__, ...)
        app.config.from_object(current_config)
        print('FIRED')  # gets printed out
    elif os.environ.get('FLASK_ENV') == 'development':
        ...
        ...

    db.init_app(app)  # <-- "app" referenced before assignment

    return app


app = create_app()
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

the development block works fine locally but when I'm running the staging config I get error on database initialization. I've read some threads and some devs solved it by making `app` a global variable which isn't ideal and I don't wanna go for that anyway. Besides it didn't help in my case.

What are the steps I can take to troubleshoot this ?

**traceback from systemd:**

```
● project.service - Gunicorn serving project
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/project.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2021-05-01 17:01:36 UTC; 10s ago
    Process: 2134 ExecStart=/home/mark/project/staging/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --preload --bind unix:project.sock -m 007 wsgi:app (code=ex>
   Main PID: 2134 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 01 17:01:36 project gunicorn[2134]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
May 01 17:01:36 project gunicorn[2134]:   File "/home/mark/project/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
May 01 17:01:36 project gunicorn[2134]:     from project import app
May 01 17:01:36 project gunicorn[2134]:   File "/home/mark/project/project/__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
May 01 17:01:36 project gunicorn[2134]:     app = create_app()
May 01 17:01:36 project gunicorn[2134]:   File "/home/mark/project/project/__init__.py", line 82, in create_app
May 01 17:01:36 project gunicorn[2134]:     db.init_app(app)
May 01 17:01:36 project gunicorn[2134]: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'app' referenced before assignment
May 01 17:01:36 project systemd[1]: project.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 01 17:01:36 project systemd[1]: project.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace/ logs from the terminal when the exception is raised ?

Comment: @Eshaan7  traceback added.

Comment: `db.init_app(app)` should be in the first `if` statement where you are creating an instance of your application. Currently, is has been referenced before assignment

Comment: That means for each environment I'll have duplicated code.

Comment: `db` is only one extension that I included in my example. If I use 6 extensions I'll have a lot of duplicated code. Plus it doesn't explain why I'm not getting the error in development.